# Elegant way of binding combobox in datagrid with a new reference of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a combobox in a datagrid which I'm binding an observable collection to.

Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DDCScheduler.View.DDCSchedule"
...
...
<DataGrid x:Name="ScheduleDataGrid" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleCollection}"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Holidays" Width="Auto">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                     FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:DDCSchedule}}, 
                     Path=DataContext.NationalHolidayCollection}"
                     DisplayMemberPath="HolidayCategoryName"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding NationalHoliday, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                  </ComboBox>
              </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code Behind

```
public partial class DDCSchedule : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Schedule> _scheduleCollection = 
        new ObservableCollection<Schedule>();
    private ObservableCollection<NationalHoliday> _nationalHolidayCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<NationalHoliday> NationalHolidayCollection
    {
        get { return _nationalHolidayCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _nationalHolidayCollection)) return;
            _nationalHolidayCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NationalHolidayCollection");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Schedule> ScheduleCollection
    {
        get { return _scheduleCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _scheduleCollection)) return;
            _scheduleCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ScheduleCollection");
        }
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isScreenLoaded)
            return;
        this.DataContext = this;
        _isScreenLoaded = true;
    }
```

Which works fine. Until I introduced the following:

```
    private void MenuItem_Settings_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsModalWindow window = new SettingsModalWindow();
        window.ShowDialog();

        if (window.DialogResult != true)
            return;

        //Assign newly created national holiday collection.
        NationalHolidayCollection = window.NationalHolidayCollection;
    }
```

Schedule.cs (Model for Datagrid's ItemSource)

```
public class Schedule : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private NationalHoliday _nationalHoliday;

    public NationalHoliday NationalHoliday
    {
        get { return _nationalHoliday; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _nationalHoliday)) return;
            _nationalHoliday = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NationalHoliday");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The SettingsModalWindow produces a new instance of the ObservableCollection inside the Settings Window. As soon as I assign the newly created observablecollection to the already bound collection, all the previously selected values in ComboBoxes in datagrid gets cleared (But the list is updated with newly bound collection).

This is an understandable behavior, since the code is assigning a newly created observablecollection from settings so that the SelectedValue is no longer referencing the same object.

My question is, what's an elegant way of solving this? It's not like I can change my model into a value type rather than reference type to overcome this.

Edit:

These are some screenshots that shows my problem. So I currently have two rows with Holiday A,B set in comboboxes.

[image]

Then I go into settings, and add more holidays (ObservableCollection inside Settings) that will show up on the comboboxes.

[image]

As soon as I press confirm, a newly created ObservableCollection is returned and assigned in the usercontrol that opened the settings modal window. As soon as assignment is done, every combobox is cleared. (But when I click on the combobox, newly created collection is properly bound)

[image]

Comment: Do you call OnPropertyChnged if you set a completely new NationalHolidayCollection?

Comment: Yes, that can be seen above in codebehind. OnPropertyChanged("NationalHolidayCollection");

Comment: Is it possible to pass the _old_ collection to the modal window and have it return a modified version? Also I think for clarity maybe a screenshot would be in order.

Comment: @Jim That was my first consideration as well. It's _possible_ yes, but in my case, it'd be much more difficult to do that. I'll upload the relevant screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in using `ObservableCollection` if you overwrite it whole, just edit its contents. I for one never even provide a setter on those collection properties.

(Implementation note: You can record all the `CollectionChanged` events in the dialog and apply their modifications to the original collection)

Comment: Would there be a more appropriate collection/data structure to handle my problem? The thing is I have some deserialization of XML going on in settings which creates a new object of ObservableCollection anyways, so modification is going to be really difficult.

Comment: @H.B. I can see how using `ObservableCollection` is a bit of overkill, but using any other collection should produce the same results, no?

Comment: @l46kok: Your application should have a way to maintain clean references, so either manage setting related stuff at startup and shutdown, or make sure your runtime objects can be associated with elements in the settings, e.g. using IDs.

Comment: @Jim: Well no, for other collections it usually needs to completely replace the source because the control does not know how to deal with them unless they implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.